# How to change the default size/geometry of tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

How do I change the default size/geometry of `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()`? I find its default size small and would like to make it wider and taller upon activation.

I am aware that:

1. Its window size can be changed manually using the mouse pointer but that is not what I am after.
2. `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()` is a `tkinter.filedialog.Directory` object which inherits from the `tkinter.commondialog.Dialog` base class. However, I have not yet figure out how to change this object size.

   ```
   # For the following classes and modules:
   #
   # options (all have default values):
   #
   # - defaultextension: added to filename if not explicitly given
   #
   # - filetypes: sequence of (label, pattern) tuples.  the same pattern
   #   may occur with several patterns.  use "*" as pattern to indicate
   #   all files.
   #
   # - initialdir: initial directory.  preserved by dialog instance.
   #
   # - initialfile: initial file (ignored by the open dialog).  preserved
   #   by dialog instance.
   #
   # - parent: which window to place the dialog on top of
   #
   # - title: dialog title
   #
   # - multiple: if true user may select more than one file
   #
   # options for the directory chooser:
   #
   # - initialdir, parent, title: see above
   #
   # - mustexist: if true, user must pick an existing directory
   #

   def askdirectory (**options):
       "Ask for a directory, and return the file name"
       return Directory(**options).show()


   # the directory dialog has its own _fix routines.
   class Directory(commondialog.Dialog):
       "Ask for a directory"

       command = "tk_chooseDirectory"

       def _fixresult(self, widget, result):
           if result:
               # convert Tcl path objects to strings
               try:
                   result = result.string
               except AttributeError:
                   # it already is a string
                   pass
               # keep directory until next time
               self.options["initialdir"] = result
           self.directory = result # compatibility
           return result
   ```

   I did an experiment trying out an option called `width`. The returned error message clearly showed it was invalid and only 4 options can be specified (i.e. `initialdir`, `mustexist`, `parent`, or `title`).

   ```
     File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/commondialog.py", line 45, in show
       s = master.tk.call(self.command, *master._options(self.options))
   _tkinter.TclError: bad option "-width": must be -initialdir, -mustexist, -parent, or -title
   ```

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/chooseDirectory.html tcl/tk documentation also does not provide such an option.

Comment: `tkinter.filedialog` is a module as indicated by the exception, do you notice how that's different from `tkinter.filedialog.FileDialog` which is a class? Also you'd need to instantiate that class to be able to access that attribute

Comment: @Matiiss Thanks. You are correct. However, I just discovered that `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()` isn't a `tkinter.filedialog.FileDialog` object. Rather it is a `tkinter.filedialog.Directory` object which is derived from the `tkinter.commondialog.Dialog` base class. Do you have any idea on how to change the geometry of this object?

Comment: There isn't such an option, probably because the native dialog on Windows makes that annoying to specify. Most of the missing features of that sort stem from the deficiencies of Win32.

Comment: @DonalFellows I ran the script in Linux and not Windows OS.